# Crashlytcs integration is taking approx 45mb+ in iOS app, is that normal?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

We are using Crashlytics for exception/crash reporting in iOS app. I am not an iOS expert and a freelance developer developed the app for us. He used the kits instead of the library, saying none available for iOS. Crashlytics Kit is taking approx 45mb+ size in iOS app whilst in Android app the library was just a few KBs. I searched the internet but cannot find anything on this subject. Am I missing something? The IPA file is 26mb without Crashlytics kit and 74mb with the kit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .ipa contains frameworks for all the supported platforms and may be pretty big. But then an actual user will download your app it will be for a specific device and the slicing will be applied which will make all the frameworks smaller.
I suggest you read this: [DTS40014195-CH1-MEASURE](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1795/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014195-CH1-MEASURE)
You will be able to see the exact size of your application per specific device and the sizes of the frameworks.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it was helpful. I was confused by the large app size appearing on the app store details. It is much smaller on the device. A bit surprized to see the large size variations on devices, will asses those further.